# Can't Send Email using Visual Basic from Windows 7 pc: "The operation has timed out"

Tags: vb.net, email, windows-7, smtp

**When trying to send an email using a Visual Basic Console App I get an error: "The operation timed out".  I'm sending from a Windows 7 pc.  Can this be done?**

I've found many posts that say it fails because there is **no SMTP client on Windows 7**.  However, I downloaded **smpt4dev** and get the same results when I try to connect to that via "localhost".

But I can telnet to the server from the same pc and get no errors. I can also send  an email using these telnet commands:

```
telnet SMTP.domain.xyz 25
helo SMTP.domain.xyz
mail from: f@domain.com
rcpt to: t@domain.com
data
subject: test email
.
quit
```

I have tried this with a few different smtp servers and I get the same results.  I know that my server name, port, username and pw are correct.

```
Imports System.Net.Mail

Try
         Dim SMTPClientObj As New Net.Mail.SmtpClient
         SMTPClientObj.UseDefaultCredentials = False
         SMTPClientObj.Credentials = New System.Net.NetworkCredential(username, password)
         SMTPClientObj.Host = "mysmtpserver"
         SMTPClientObj.Port = 25
         SMTPClientObj.EnableSsl = False

         Dim e_mail As New MailMessage()
         e_mail.From = New MailAddress("test@test.com")
         e_mail.To.Add("test2@test.com")
         e_mail.Subject = "Email Sending Test"
         e_mail.IsBodyHtml = False
         e_mail.Body = "Test email from VB"

         SMTPClientObj.Send(e_mail)

         Dim x As New Mail.SmtpStatusCode
         Console.WriteLine("SmtpStatusCode: " & CStr(x))

         Console.WriteLine("Mail Sent.")

    Catch ex As Exception
         Dim x As New Mail.SmtpStatusCode
         Console.WriteLine("SmtpStatusCode: " & CStr(x))
         MsgBox(ex.Message)
         MsgBox(ex.ToString)
         MsgBox(ex.InnerException)
    End Try
```

At this point I'd just like to be able to get more details on the error instead of the simple timed out message.  But I've never used the SmtpStatusCode before and am not sure how to use it.

The ex.InnerException prompt is always blank.

Can you give me any pointers on how to get more detailed error info?  Or what I need to do to get this to work on my windows 7 pc?

Thank you

Comment: If you're not getting exceptions when trying to use the SMTPClient, then there is one available. There's no issue with using SMTPClient on Windows 7. You do have to have an actual account at an SMTP server with which you can connect, and a timeout indicates that you're not able to make that connection. Either your server is invalid or you have a networking issue that's preventing you from accessing it using the IP address and port you're using. Have you read the documentation for your SMTP server account to see how they expect you to set things up?

Comment: Ken, thanks for the response. I know my server and port info are correct as other developers have used it successfully in java on non windows 7 machines.  And if I change my port to 587 I get an immediate response saying "Failure sending memo."  I have not read the documentation for the SMTP server account because this is a large company and I don't have access to it.  Is there something specific I should look for?  Thank you

Comment: Usually it's the port and security setup that causes these sorts of issues. If you have other developers that are sending emails successfully, you should be talking to them about how they're setting things up, shouldn't you? If it's your own company's SMTP server you're connecting with, your IT staff should also be able to help you with the proper configuration, and networking staff should be able to monitor the connection attempt to help figure out what's going wrong.

Comment: I don't think this is **`vba`**, it's **`vb`** Visual Basic console app?

Comment: I am talking to other developers and using the same setups they are, that's what makes this so confusing.  And i'm trying to contact network staff but things move a little slow around here.

Comment: Correct, it's a vb console app.  Not vba.

Comment: Code looks OK assuming you are filling in correct values for user, pw and host. Does a typical client like Outlook or Thunderbird send email from your PC using the same settings? That would eliminate network issues. Perhaps AV blocking your app???

Comment: I've been asking around and it could be McAfee or a group policy that's blocking port 25.  But we're heading into a 3 day weekend so the people I need to talk to aren't in.  I'm going to put this on hold and get back to it next week. Thanks for the input.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out **Digital Guardian was blocking port 25**.  McAfee wasn't the problem nor was Group policy.

Thanks to everyone for their assistance.